# Show that A is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $X^m-1$ for some positive integer $m$.  
 
$a)$ Show that $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$. 
$b)$ Show that $tr(A)$ is a sum of roots of $X^m-1$.

Comment: Can you provide any thoughts, work, motivation, or context?

Comment: Hints: (1) All eigenvalues of $A$ are $m$th roots of unity.  (2) If you know the Jordan form, can you prove that all blocks are size $1$ by contradiction?

Comment: What have you tried? Were are you getting stuck?  Do you know what an eigenvalue is?  Do you know what a minimal polynomial is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic theorem of linear algebra is that a matrix is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial is the product of distinct linear factors.

Since the ground field is $\mathbb{C}$ the polynomial $x^n-1$ factors into linear factors and its well know that they are distinct ( because the polynomial is prime to its derivative $nx^{n-1}$). Thus $A$ is diagonalizable as its minimal polynomial must divide this polynomial.